# FMDB executeupdate hangs when calling

Tags: fmdb

I am using FMDB to procedd sqlitedb in obj-c , but it hangs everytime i call executeupdate

```
BOOL isSuccess = YES;

[self openFMDB];
NSString* currentDatetime = [self getCurrentDatetime];

isSuccess = [fmDB executeUpdate:@"UPDATE liquors_list SET l_last_open = ? WHERE l_id = ?",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentDatetime],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",liquorID],Nil];

return isSuccess;
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? I encounter a similar issue on multiple database  open calls (even if closed).

Comment: What do all the backtraces say?